# Predicate works on FetchedResults but not on FetchRequest

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

I want to add a predicate to a FetchRequest...

##### It is not working if i put it into the FetchRequest:

`not working`

```swift
@SectionedFetchRequest(sectionIdentifier: \Product.manufacturer?.name, 
                       sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Product.name, ascending: true)], 
                       predicate: NSPredicate(format: "trashed = true")) // <-- not working

var products: SectionedFetchResults<String?, Product>
```

##### but it is working when i add it to the FetchedResults with `.onChange`

`working`

```swift
@SectionedFetchRequest(sectionIdentifier: \Product.manufacturer?.name, 
                       sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Product.name, ascending: true)], 
                      // -- no predicate in FetchRequest --)

var products: SectionedFetchResults<String?, Product>

var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(products) { product in
            Text(product.name)
        }
        Button {
            testPred.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("activate predicate")
        }
    }
}
.onChange(of: isSortedAscending) { _ in
    products.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "trashed = true") // <-- working
}
```

---

`edit 1`

The only idea I have right now is to ask if this could have something to do with these settings?

```swift
publicDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions = options
publicDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
publicDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
```

Comment: `NSPredicate(format: "isTrashed == YES")` is also not working

Comment: I am a bit confused why you have posted a new question for this but could you please remove at least one of them since they seems to be duplicates and since the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem, but I could really go crazy right now!

The predicate has worked all the time. 
However, I had attached this code to the view:

```swift
.onReceive(tabaccoName.$debounced) { query in
            /// don't filter when searchbar is empty
            guard !query.isEmpty else {
                tabaccos.nsPredicate = nil // <-- PROBLEM
                return
            }
            
            /// set filter when someone searches
            tabaccos.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[cd] %@", argumentArray: [#keyPath(Tabacco.name), query])
        }
```

And this one immediately set the Predicate to `nil` every time again.